# How to apply a Gaussian filter to co-ordinate data

Tags: matlab, filter, fft, gaussian, data-representation

I have taken a highly detailed trace of a surface in order to try and calculate the Surface Roughness eg. Ra or Rz. Before I can calculate these parameters I need to separate the Form and the Waviness (longer wavelengths) from the profile of the surface leaving just the Roughness.

It has been specified that the filter used to extract the Roughness must be Gaussian. The transition point between Roughness and Form is a variable I wish to be able to change.

I have found this [link](http://physics.mercer.edu/hpage/filter/gauss.html) useful in my research so far but not fully explanatory.

Does anyone know how to write a Gaussian filter like in the link so that I can create a graph of the Roughness values? I want to be able to do this ideally in Matlab or excel but would be open to C or other programming languages as well.

Update 21/01/2015

I believe what I need to do is find the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of the raw profile to calculate the wavelengths of the components of the curve and then apply the Gaussian transmission characteristics to all of the wavelengths in accordance with ISO 16610 but I still don't see how to find the amplitude of the FFT frequencies or their position at any point on the curve?

Comment: maybe something like [fspecial](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html)?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to find the surface roughness of a terrain given a 3D model. I'm not sure how to do this on a continuous surface, but if you're willing to discretise it you can try the method given in
[Hoffman and Krotkov, 1989] Hoffman, R. and Krotkov, E., _Terrain Roughness Measurement from Elevation Maps_.
Proc. SPIE Mobile Robots, Vol. 4, pp 104-114, Philadelphia,
USA, 1989.

Comment: That is similar to what I am trying to achieve however my surface trace was only along one direction on the surface meaning I have a 2D graph. Before I can calculate the value of surface roughness I need to use a filter on this graph so that I am only measuring the small changes e.g. if the part had been measured at an angle then this angle would be removed from the graph or if the cutting tool used to make the part created lay on the surface this would be removed so that only the fine detail of the surface remains.